# Coupling married people so that no couples are spouses

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the following problem, taken from the book *Understanding Probability* by Henk Tijms.

> Suppose $n=10$ married couples are invited to a bridge party. Bridge
>   partners are chosen at random, without regard to gender. What is the
>   probability that no one will be paired with his or her spouse?

My approach is as follows. There are $2n=20$ people involved in the bridge tournament. The probability that the first player is not coupled with his spouse is $\frac{18}{19}$. The probability that the first member of the second team is not coupled with his spouse is $\frac{16}{17}$. So the probability that no team consists of a married coupled is:
$$
P=\prod_{k=1}^9\frac{2k}{2k+1}\simeq 0.284.
$$

A different way of obtaining the same result is:
The possible number of pairings is $20!$. The number of ways to choose the first player is $\binom{20}{1}=20$. The number of ways to choose the second player (the one in team with player 1), excluding his spouse, is $18$. For the third player, we have no constraints so the number of ways of chosing the third player is again $18$. For the fourth player, we have to keep out the spouse of the third player, so the number of possible choices are $16$. The final result is:
$$
P = \frac{\binom{20}{1}}{20!}\prod_{k=1}^9 (2k)^2\simeq 0.284.
$$

However, the result is wrong. There must be a flaw in my reasoning.

Edit: after the help from @anton-v and @lord-shark-the-unknown, let me try again by applying the inclusion-exclusion rule.
Start by counting the number of pairings where only one couple is matched. To this end, choose one element out of 20, and match it with his spouse. The remaining ways to fill a list of 20 players after having chosen two is $\frac{18!}{20!}$. The number of ways to chose a single couple out of 10 possible couples is $ \binom{10}{1}$. The first term in the inclusion-exclusion rule is then:
$$
P(\text{1 couple}) = \binom{10}{1}20\frac{18!}{20!}.
$$
For the second couple, we have similarly $\cdot\binom{10}{2}$ ways to select two couples out of ten, then for the first player we have 20 choices, and 18 for the third player. The remaining 16 places can be filled in $16!$ ways.
The second term in the inclusion-exclusion rule is:
$$
P(\text{2 couples})= \binom{10}{2}20\cdot18\frac{16!}{20!},
$$
which will be summed with the negative sign.

The required probability will be:
$$
P=\sum_{k=1}^{10}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{10}{k}\frac{(20-2k)!}{20!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(20-j) = \sum_{k=1}^{10}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{10}{k}\frac{(20-2k)!}{20!}\frac{20!!}{(20-2k)!!}\simeq 0.409
$$
which is indeed the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take a male player $A$, and correctly assert that the probability he is not
paired with his spouse is $18/19$. Now you take another male player $B$; what is the probability he is not paired with his spouse? You need to
condition on the probability that $A$ is paired with $B$'s spouse. The probability that $B$ is not paired with his spouse conditional on $A$ not being paired with her is $16/17$ but the
probability that $B$ is not paired with his spouse conditional on $A$ being paired with her is one. You need to use the law of total probability to find the probability that $B$ is not paired with his spouse.

As this approach becomes more complex as one continues, I would try using
the inclusion/exclusion principle instead.

Comment: Doesn't the derangement formula work here. The ways in which none will be paired with his or her spouse will be simply
$$!10=\left\lfloor{\frac {10!}{e}+\frac {1}{2}}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: @Manthanein I don't think so.

Comment: Will you please explain the reason 'cause I am a bit weak at derangement.

Comment: Yeah I got the answer.  Because even a male could be paired with a male instead of a female. Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 2):

For the first, second person and third, you are correct. However, the chance that the fourth person is not
 the third person's spouse, is not simply $\frac{16}{17}$. Both the first and second person could be the spouse of this person, which means that all $17$ remaining people are allowed matches for the third person.

I hope this observation allows you to calculate the probability correctly.