# Permutations of pairs with no pair ending up together.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, mathematical-modeling

I'm working on a general version of the problem linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590059/coupling-married-people-so-that-no-couples-are-spouses).

To quote the original:

> Suppose =10 married couples are invited to a bridge party. Bridge partners are chosen
> at random, without regard to gender. What is the probability that no one will be paired with his or her spouse?

The approach that the original poster uses is the inclusion-exclusion principle which makes sense. However, I'm not really understanding how they end up at their final equation:

> $P=\sum_{k=1}^{10}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{10}{k}\frac{(20-2k)!}{20!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(20-j) = \sum_{k=1}^{10}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{10}{k}\frac{(20-2k)!}{20!}\frac{20!!}{(20-2k)!!}$

More specifically, how I'm thinking of modelling this problem is that you line up all the individuals in a given order. Index these people by their position in the line, starting at 1. Then the couples formed are (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), etc. There are $20!$ such orders.

Let $O$ be the set of all orderings. Let $ON$ be the set of permutations in which no spouses are together. Let $O_i$ be the set of all orders in which the $i^{th}$ couple are spouses.  Then to find the number of orderings in which *no* couples are spouses, we can compute:

> $|ON| = |O| - |\cup_{i=1}^{i=10}|$

Clearly $|O| = 20!$. Computing $|\cup_{i=1}^{i=10}|$ is where I need the inclusion exclusion principle:

> $|\cup_{i=1}^{i=10}| = \sum_{i = 1}^{10}|A_i| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 10}|A_i \cap A_j| + ... + (-1)^{n-1}|\cap_{i=1}^{10}A_i|$

I agree with the original poster that the $n^{th}$ term/summation of the above equation should be computed as:

${10 \choose n}2^n\frac{10!}{(10-n)!}*(20-2n)!$

Here ${10 \choose n}$ is the number of different groups of $n$ couples we can fix to be spouses, $2^k$ is the ways each of these couples can be ordered, $\frac{10!}{(10-n)!}$ is the number of positions these couples can take among the $10$ couples, and the finally $(20-2n)!$ are the number of permutations of the other - not necessarily matched - couples. Then using the inclusion exclusion principle I would end up with the summation:

$|\cup_{i=1}^{i=10}| = (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{i = 1}^{10}{10 \choose n}2^n\frac{10!}{(10-n)!}*(20-2n)!$

However I'm lost as to how this is equivalent to the original poster's equation above, and it gets a very different numerical answer. Where am I going wrong here?